# Passing arguments through Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java Swing so my question maybe is a little bit vague.
I already have a Java Project and i need to create a GUI where a user will give in a ''box''  4-5 values and these will be passed into my already existing project.

p.s Any help even a tutorial about this is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Passed in how?  How will your already existing project be run?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is this "box"? And what kinds of values will it contain? What is the interface for your already existing project? Are you allowed to modify it if necessary?

Comment: Very vague question...

Comment: This tutorial may be of interest. It includes a GUI form using Swing. http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-calculator

Comment: Not sure, but why do not try to use environment parameters to do it.

Comment: Biggest tip I can offer for you: `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: yes it will be the interface of my existing project.E.g i need a box with title "Total Epochs" where the user will give a value and i need this value to use it in my project int total_epochs= this value

Comment: Simply use a `JPanel` to hold your components, on which you will take input from the user, and save it in some variables. And put this `JPanel` to the `JOptionPane` by using [JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parent, Object message)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)), simply pass the object of the `JPanel`in place of Object.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do this.
In the constructor of your Component (e.g. JFrame) you pass a reference to your Object.

You assign this object, to am internal variable of the Component (JFrame) so that it is accessible to methods such as event listeners.

In this way you can have interaction with your Project.

### Example:

In the below example we have a thread in main that prints the value of the Person every second.
At the same time, when the JFrame is used to change the value it is visible.

It provides a basic example on how to modify existing Objects from within a GUI.

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class NameEnterForm extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField NameField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final Person ObjectToPass = new Person();
                    NameEnterForm frame = new NameEnterForm(ObjectToPass);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    Runnable printThread = new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while(true)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Print Value:"+ ObjectToPass.getName());
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }                       
                    };

                    new Thread(printThread).start();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    private Person ObjectToPass;
    private JButton btnGetName;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public NameEnterForm(Person ObjectToPassRef) {

        //Set the object to class field
        this.ObjectToPass = ObjectToPassRef; 

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 110);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton SaveName = new JButton("Save Name");
        SaveName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ObjectToPass.setName(NameField.getText());
            }
        });
        SaveName.setBounds(10, 42, 118, 23);
        contentPane.add(SaveName);

        NameField = new JTextField();
        NameField.setBounds(66, 11, 206, 20);
        contentPane.add(NameField);
        NameField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 14, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        btnGetName = new JButton("Get Name");
        btnGetName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Name is:" + ObjectToPass.getName());
            }
        });
        btnGetName.setBounds(138, 42, 118, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGetName);
    }
}

class Person
{

    private String Person;

    public void setName(String Person)
    {
        this.Person = Person;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Person;
    }
}
```